# MVC validation, Regular expression for a rounded hour

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

I would like to implement a validation of a property using the RegularExpression attribute to check if the time entered by the user is rounded to the nearest quarter hour (02:15, 02:00,02:45, 02:30 match but not 02:12).

I tried the following one, but it doesn't work.

```
 [RegularExpression("([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):(([0][0])|([1][5]|[3][0]|[4][5]))]
 public DateTime StartHour { get; set; }
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: did you forget to close the RegularExpression string? `[RegularExpression("([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):(([0][0])|([1][5]|[3][0]|[4][5])")]` or maybe just a typo?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your English.

Answer (score 3):

`([01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):(00|15|30|45)` should work.

Comment: Yes of course. @Pandore, would you mind accepting my answer if you're gonna use it? Just click the tick.

Answer (score 0):

`^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):(00|15|30|45)$` should work; `^` = start of string `([01][0-9]|2[0-3])` = (0 or 1 followed by 0-9) or 2 followed by 0-3 a literal colon followed by one of 00, 15, 30 or 45 `$` = end of string

Comment: I tried it but I got a validation error message in both cases if the value matchs or not (for instance 10:15 and 10:10). I also tried to add "-" between 0 and 1 in [01], but it still not working.